# Static images in the react-native

Tags: react-native

How should I work with static images in RN?
Let say I have a component which is call `<Flag />`.
The Flag can access to assets of many *.png image files (flags).
So, for example, you can ask for Japan's flag like this:
`<Flag type="Japan" />`

So there exist around 193 flags.
The code for switch bettwen images looks like this:

```
import USA from '../assets/images/flags/USA.png';
import Japan from '../assets/images/flags/Japan.png';
import Slovakia from '../assets/images/flags/Slovakia.png';
...


const getSource = (type) => {
switch(type) {
  case 'Japan':
     return Japan;
case 'USA':
  return USA;

    ...

  }
}
```

and render method  looks like this:

```
return (
<Image source={getSource(type)} />
)
```

1. Is this approach OK even if there exist 193 flags?
   Because if I decided to use images with different screen densities

```
flag.png
    ├── flag@2x.png
    └── flag@3x.png
```

then I will have 193 * 3 (597) images files.  So it means that bundle for this component will be big right? Exist there a better way how to do that?

2. What is the best resolution for these images?

Answer (score 0):

```
let imagesInDisk = {
    'Peru': require('/path/to/flag/images/Peru.png'),
    'Chile': require('/path/to/flag/images/Chile.png'),
    ...
}
```

then in render:

```
return <Image source={imagesInDisk[countryName]} />
```

No need to use a different "import" for each image file.

Thanks to Grund for comment!

Comment: I don't expect that this will be work because the react-native expected that the image name in require has to be known statically.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html

Comment: This improvement above will be work but It basically works like my current solution with imports, your is maby just less verbose but I create an npm script which is generating this function for me form object.

Comment: Aha. I see. Then, I didn't get what you want... but probably you have your answer already.